# i can't connect between app URLs in Django

Tags: python, django

I have a small problem with URLs file in Django,
I'm trying to connect between app URLs, review, and the main urls

I have

- python 3.9.1
- Django 3.2.0

I have been searching and try many things on StackOverflow but still, I don't find why the server doesn't work just when I put this line with a red arrow on the comment,
please help!!

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One typo I can see is in signup/urls.py-

Change `URLPattern` to `urlpatterns`. Let me know if that fixes the issue in the comment?

Answer (score 1):

In your `signup` folder's `urls.py` file replace `URLPattern` to `urlpatterns`.

Try:

```
urlpatterns = [
    ...
]
```

Happy coding :)